# Global variable not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-elixir, rollupjs

I am trying to get global variables working in node.js, but it seems like I don't really understand the concept, even though my understanding matches the documentation.

## Minimal example

My **main.js** file, which is compiled using rollup is:

```
global.a = 1;
require('./core/test.js');
```

My **core/test.js** file is simply:

```
console.log(a);
```

This causes the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

The fully compiled output is:

```
(function (exports) {
'use strict';

var commonjsGlobal = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : {};

console.log(a);

commonjsGlobal.a = 1;

}((this.LaravelElixirBundle = this.LaravelElixirBundle || {})));
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjpudWxsLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIkM6L3dhbXAvd3d3L3V1YmMvcmVzb3VyY2VzL2Fzc2V0cy9qcy9jb3JlL3Rlc3QuanMiLCJDOi93YW1wL3d3dy91dWJjL3Jlc291cmNlcy9hc3NldHMvanMvYXBwLmpzIl0sInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbImNvbnNvbGUubG9nKGEpO1xyXG4iLCJnbG9iYWwuYSA9IDE7XHJcbnJlcXVpcmUoJy4vY29yZS90ZXN0LmpzJyk7XHJcbiJdLCJuYW1lcyI6WyJnbG9iYWwiXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiI7Ozs7O0FBQUEsT0FBTyxDQUFDLEdBQUcsQ0FBQyxDQUFDLENBQUMsQ0FBQzs7QUNBZkEsY0FBTSxDQUFDLENBQUMsR0FBRyxDQUFDLENBQUM7OyJ9
```

It seems that `a` gets defined *after* `console.log(a);`. I'm not 100% sure if this matters in JS but it could be causing the error.

So my question is: what causes this, and what am I doing wrong here?

Possibly relevant information: I'm using Laravel Elixir to compile everything.

Note: Please don't post discussion on whether or not to use global variables in node.js or in general. I know it's usually a bad idea, but I have a very good reason to do it in this case.

### Edit: Additional context

What I'm really trying to do is getting Zurb Foundation to work with Laravel Elixir though node.js. I installed `foundation-sites` through NPM. `foundation-sites` relies on `jquery`, which it pulls in itself. *However*, Foundation doesn't seem to follow the usual conventions of just using something like `var jquery = require('jquery');` in its own js file. It actually relies upon a global `jQuery` variable being available. Therefore I have to ensure that somehow.

My actual file looks like this:

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
require('foundation-sites');
```

So if there are any Foundation/Laravel-specific anwers I would be very happy to hear them as well. Is there something I'm not getting, or did Foundation just not create their package the "right" way?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Alright, edited it to the bottom.

Comment: it seems that global is just another object, that happens to be named "global". If you put something in there with: global.a = 1 then you should be able to get it out with: console.log(global.a).

Comment: @Kokodoko: No. NodeJS [defines `global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like an issue with your bundler not respecting the order you're doing those two lines in. Your source is clearly:

```
global.a = 1;
require('./core/test.js');
```

...but the bundled result is clearly the other way around:

```
console.log(a);
commonjsGlobal.a = 1;
```

It seems like it's hoisting the `require` calls. In general, having `require` calls that need to be done at a particular point in the execution control flow is not best practice (in fact, when defining modules for ES2015, `import` is explicitly defined as not being executed in the module's step-by-step control flow).

So if you need to do this, you'll probably want to look at another bundler. But check that it supports order other than dependency resolution order.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking too. Do you have a link to the documentation that says `import` is explicitly defined as not being executed in the module's step-by-step control flow?

Comment: By the way, I added some additional context to the question. Perhaps you know more about this too?

Answer (score 3):

You are right that it should work. Here's a working example:

```
// file1.js
global.a = 'hello';
require('./file2');

// file2.js
console.log(a);
```

Run `node file1.js`, and you'll see `'hello'` printed to the console.

It looks like you've got some other tool being used (Laravel / Elixir). Use node directly and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved this in a pretty simple way, by using `browserify` instead of `rollup`. Thanks for the other answers pointing me in the right direction. It's not a perfect solution, and I still don't fully understand what the differences are between the two, but it'll do for this project.

The relevant part of my gulpfile:

```
mix.browserify('app.js','public/js/app.js');
```

To use `browserify` with Laravel Elixir, I used

```
npm install laravel-elixir-browserify-official --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for **rollup** by providing an `output.intro` that sets up the required variables. In your case this would be:

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  // ...
  output: {
    // ...
    intro: `let a = 1;`
  }
};
```

Admittedly this qualifies as a hack, but solves the bundling problem in my case (where switching away from rollup is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, only when using `import`. Solved the problem this way:

```
// main.js
import './globals.js';
import './file.js';

// globals.js
global.a = 123;

// file.js
console.log(a);
```